# Best power supply configuration

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, filter, buck, tvs

I'm making a power supply board with a buck converter for a 2A maximum and I would to know which is the best configuration between these two:
[image]

Is it best to put the input filter, a parallel damped LC filter), after or before the efuse (TPS2640 https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tps2640)?

Comment: So this all boils down to if fuse or filter should be first? OK, what are fuses used for and why? Do you want to protect what with the fuse?

Comment: @Justme Fuse performs reverse polarity protection, inrush current control and current limiter, and i want to protect multiple boards and sensors in automotive environment

Comment: So could the output of the filter possibly be shorted to ground?  If so, put the fuse before the filter.

Comment: @JohnD Why should the output of the filter goes to short circuit? If the buck or some capacitors are broken yes

Comment: @Gigapel That's for you to evaluate. Buck input caps short? Someone adjusts something nearby and slips with a screwdriver?  I don't have any idea what your system is and how it's built, tested, and operated so only you can evaluate the risk of a short on any given node in your design.  If the risk in negligible, then it doesn't need fuse protection.